# Can API request be authenticated with AWS signature using Playwright?

Tags: authentication, playwright, web-api-testing, aws-signature

Description:
If I need to submit a GET/POST request using APIrequest methods provided in Playwright. Can I authenticate using AWS signature to initiate the APIrequestContext

I have tried authenticating using Bearer token authorization by providing the token in 'extraHTTPHeaders' while initiate the APIrequestCOntext. which worked perfectly fine.

However, when we don't have Bearer token and want to authorize using AWS signature. Is it possible with Playwright functions

Note: I am able to achieve the same by using aws4 package .sign method, for which we use https package methods to submit API request. But here I am looking to utilize playwright API methods specifically in this context.